# Camera manipulations in my activity

Tags: android, camera, android-camera, android-video-player

I know I can fire an intent and start the camera, but I want to do something else. And I need the camera included in my own activity.

Let say this is an activity with black background, and the down part is some buttons or whatever and the upper part the gray area needs to be some view that will show the view from the camera. All I want to do is to stream the camera output in to my own view as a part of my own activity.

Is this possible ?, and if it is how can I do this.

Thanks,
[image]

Comment: you mean you want to set the camera View in to just that gray colored square. right ??

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. However, it takes quite a lengthy code to do it, so instead of going into detail, I suggest you check out a great tutorial in [Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html). As you can see, there are two ways of using a camera in Android - firing an intent, or implementing a customized camera. The [Building a Camera App](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#custom-camera) section provides clear guidelines for getting customized look for your camera. In short, you need to

- check if camera is available
- fire the camera
- (if necessary) check supported features
- implement preview (i.e., display live imaging from the camera)
- place that preview to your custom layout
- capture and save images (seems to be irrelevant according to your question)
- release the camera when done!